# Load Dynamic Web Page with IP from User Input Java HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, dynamic

I am trying to load a page dynamically with IP address input using java without using anything fancy like ajax etc...

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>
TESTPAGE
</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<font color=#C6ED2C><center>
TESTPAGE<p></p><p></p>

<script>
function setURL(url){
    document.getElementById('demo').src = url;
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript"> IP = prompt("Please enter IP of Device", ""); 
document.write("<p></p>Page is now custom for " + IP + ", Enjoy."); 
</script>
<iframe Id="demo" src="http//" + IP + "/" width="300" height="350"></iframe>
<p>TEST1:  <input type="button" value=".:: Load Page ::." onclick="setURL('"http://"+IP+"/index.html"')" /> <input type="button" value=".:: LoadPage2 ::." onclick="setURL('http://" + IP + "/index2')" />

</font>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

basically where I want the frame and the buttons to also point to this IP as well but a different html page on the IP... I know its an oddball request for a personal project I want to use locally to access local information but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you're taking input on client side then why can't just update the IFrame source ?

Comment: You can but there is several more buttons and links to the full code ... to some stuff on the LAN. So when the IP changes I just want to enter the IP once and dynamically change all the rest of the code just the IP portion of the link via the IP I enter when prompted.